# Last digits of a card are the same

Tags: probability

I have a question

If I have a certain card, with for example 10 digits. 
Do you think that is it possible that someone else have the same last 4 digits of my card?

I think that is possible. Because if the number has 10 digits I only care about the first six digits. that can be any number between 0 and 9, so there are $10^6$ possibilities to create another card with the same last 4 digits as mine.

Am I thinking correctly? Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: There are $10^4=10000$ possibilities for the last 4 digits.  So, 1 out of 10,000 is unlikely, but certainly possible.  If you want to use your value of the first 6 digits, it would be used like this: there are $10^{10}$ total possibilities for the card and $10^6$ different first digits for each last 4. Thus your probability is $\frac{10^6}{10^{10}}$ which gives you the same result as in the first part of my comment.

Comment: Those 10000 are 0000, 0001, 0002 ... 9997,9998,9999

Comment: Because of the algorithm used in generating credit card numbers, and the check digit, and the limitations of the prefix to specific banks, the odds are BETTER than 1 in 10,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is correct.  If there are more than a million such cards, it is certain that two of them share the same last four digits.  It is still possible (but unlikely) that your last four digits are unique.  Maybe there are $10^7$ cards out there with all possibilities for the first seven digits represented and all three of the last being $000$.  If your last three are not $000$, there are no duplicates for you.  Assuming the numbers are unique, there are $10^6-1$ other numbers that would match yours in the last four digits.

Comment: Hi, I did not understand why If my last three digits are not 000
there are no duplicates. Can you explain it better please? thanks

Comment: I just hypothesized a distribution where all the other cards end in 000.  In that case there are no duplicates.  That is an unlikely distribution, but it is possible.